# VS Intellisense does not recognize ADO objects

Tags: sql-server, visual-c++, visual-studio-2019, intellisense

Minimal example in Visual Studio 2019 (copy pasted into a new C++ Console project):

```cpp
#import "C:/Program Files/Common Files/System/ado/msado15.dll" no_namespace rename("EOF", "EndOfFile")  
int main()
{
    CoInitialize(NULL);
    _RecordsetPtr pRs("ADODB.Recordset");
    _ConnectionPtr pCn("ADODB.Connection");
    pCn->Provider = "sqloledb";
}
```

This program runs correctly, however in the IDE, the `_RecordsetPtr` and `_ConnectionPtr` are underlined with red squiggle and tooltip "identifier _RecordsetPtr is undefined" etc., and then intellisense is of course unavailable for `pCn->` and so on.

How do I fix it so that IntelliSense works here?

Note - if I don't include the full path in the `#import` line then it gives the error `fatal error C1083: Cannot open type library file: 'msado15.dll': No such file or directory`.  Some online code examples included the full path and some didn't.

---

*Background:* I'm ultimately attempting to call a database stored procedure on SQL Server on local network, from a non-MFC C++ project. The MSDN documentation indicates that SQLNCLI is deprecated and should not be used in new code, and OLEDB is recommended instead.  MSDN didn't have any code examples for OLEDB though, and a third party site did have some but it is hundreds of lines of code to use the OLEDB COM interfaces without using ADO, so there seems to be the recommendation to use ADO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test on my side, and looks like VS can’t find the generated `.tlh` file.

The error disappeared after I manually added the path(Debug folder directory which includes msado15.tlh file) to project’s property(Configuration Properties > VC++ Directories > Include Directories).

Perhaps you can have a try.

[image]

Comment: OK, that worked insofaras intellisense now does show the list of members under `->`  ; although "Go to Declaration" still gives an error that declaration could not be loaded. (Is there another way to do it so that it it possible to interact with the code from importing the type library?)

Answer (score 1):

Considering ADO is not going to change any time soon, it is feasible to add
the actual .tlh and .tli files to your project. You can even change them to .h and .cpp and clean up things inside of it. Additionally this allows IntelliSense and other things to understand and find the definitions for this stuff *before* having to build / compile the project to generate those files!

Personally, I always preferred saving the generated .tlh and .tli files anyway so there is consistency when building, though that removes the whole point of being able to dynamically generate code based on a type library that may be changing.

By removing #import you also are able to take advantage of some other things like parallel compilation.